# MySQL Query for Average of last 2 attempts

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
quiz userid  attempt grade

1      3        1     33

2      3        1     67

1      3        2     90

10     3        4     20

2      3        2     67

1      3        3     55
```

Now For first quiz, an user gave 3attempts i.e., (33, 90, 55), Now I need the average for last 2 attempts ( (90 + 55)/2) for that scormid and userid too

Now, I want the last two attempts i.e., 4 and 3 and I want average grade of these 2 grades i.e, 90 and 20
Need the OP like

`userid` `quiz`  `No.of Attempts`      `Grade`

```
3      1         3           (90+55)/2 i.e., 72.5
3      2         2            (67+67)/2 i.e., 67
3      10        1               20
```

Comment: Can you have more users or quizzes? If so, how should that be handled?

Comment: what's wrong with @rich_adams 's answer? If you don't get it, you might want to add that to the question, but it looks good, doesn't it?

Comment: In Rich Adams query, Iam getting only one row, but i should get all the rows for the quiz

Answer (score 6):

First you need to select just the two rows with highest attempts, which is what the subquery does, then average the grades from the derived table.

```
SELECT 
    AVG(grade) 
FROM (
      SELECT 
          grade 
      FROM 
          `table`
      ORDER BY attempt DESC 
      LIMIT 2
     ) t;
```

This will give you a result of `55.0000`, which is the average of 90 and 20, the grades for the last two attempts.

Comment: Why using a subquery if you can use a GROUP BY statement?

Comment: Because a GROUP BY will show you the average for each attempt value, not the combined average, which is what I think the OP wants (although that may not be what they're after).

Comment: OP wants the averages per attempt, i thought

Comment: I'm not sure this will work the general case -- of more users or quizzes :( This seems like a case for "group-by-bottom-n".

Comment: I want to get the last two attempts and and get average by calculating both the grades (90 and 20) and all in one column I need the output

Comment: @Michiel Ah, I thought they wanted average of two grades. I guess it's up to the OP to decide what it is they're actually after :)

Comment: @pst Agreed, additional users/quizes will definitely not work with my query.

Comment: Hi Rich Adams,When i execute your query, it gives an error "Every derived table must have its own alias"  Could you suggest me where I went wrong

Comment: @user1067018 You're missing the "t" part at the end. That "t" is the alias for the derived table. "... FROM (...) t;"

Comment: Hi Rich Adams,                                                    SELECT 
    scormid, AVG(grade),element
FROM (
      SELECT 
          scormid, value,element
      FROM 
          mdl_scorm_scoes_track WHERE element='cmi.core.score.raw'
      ORDER BY attempt DESC 
      LIMIT 2
     ) t
Iam getting only one row and it is taking total average of all attempts, But I need only avergae grade for last two attempts

Comment: @user1067018 I don't see how the query you've pasted would work. You're selecting the average of grade "AVG(grade)", but there's no "grade" column selected from the inner table, only "scormid, value, element". If it's "value", then the outer query should be "AVG(value)" instead. If it really does need to be "grade", then you should also select "grade" on the inner table so that it's available to the outer query.

Comment: This is the one I tried atlast                                      SELECT userid, quiz, attempt, AVG(grade) FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track ORDER BY attempt DESC LIMIT 2 It displays a wrong percentage value (I think it is taking all the 3 attempts average, but I need only last two attempts

Comment: @user1067018 Yeah, if you don't have a subquery it will give you the average of all values. LIMIT doesn't restrict what is evaluated, so AVG is being evaluated on all rows, not just the latest 2. I notice the question has been updated since I answered to include multiple quizzes, which definitely won't work with my answer :( To get average of last two attempts per quiz makes this more complicated. You can add a WHERE clause to the subquery to get the average for a specific quiz ("WHERE quiz = 1", etc), but I can't think of a way off the top of my head of getting all quizzes in one query :(

Comment: Ok Cool, Thank You, Don't try to think more

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AVG(grade), attempt
FROM table
GROUP BY attempt
ORDER BY attempt DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Hi Guys, I need to display only last two attempts please, so that i could try for avg

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the last two rows = selecting the first two rows of a reversed set.

Simply order by `attempt` DESC (that makes it 4,3,2,1) and then grab the first two (4,3).

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE <...> ORDER BY attempt DESC LIMIT 2`

Comment: Hi Tom, Lets work on your suggestion SELECT userid, quiz, attempt, AVG(grade) FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track ORDER BY attempt DESC LIMIT 2

It displays a wrong percentage value (I think it is taking all the 3 attempts average, but I need only last two attempts

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming your table is called 'grades')

```
SELECT last_two_grades.userid, last_two_grades.quiz, AVG(last_two_grades.grade) AS average
  FROM (
        SELECT grades.userid, grades.quiz, grades.grade
          FROM grades
      ORDER BY grades.attempt DESC
         LIMIT 2
       ) AS last_two_grades
GROUP BY last_two_grades.userid, last_two_grades.quiz
```

With that you can select the average of the last two grades on a per user basis. If you want to select it for a specific user you can do so by adding

```
HAVING last_two_grades.userid = 3
```

to the end of the query and for a certain quiz you can add

```
HAVING last_two_grades.quiz = 1
```

and to get the average grades for a user at a certain quiz you must specify

```
HAVING last_two_grades.quiz = 1 AND last_two_grades.userid = 3
```

Comment: The output displays like this                                         userid     average     3  662019123                               only one row

Comment: Of course. You want to know the grades average of the last two attempts of a user right? why are you expecting more than one row per user? Oh, and I just saw that attempts can be the same values for one user, so you must specify another order (respectively group by or where) criteria... i guess the quiz is the thing to go...

Comment: Hi Vapire, still i get only one row, i need the OP as stated above under my question. Please kindly check

Answer (score 0):

Makes 2 assumption: that all you attempts are sequential and have no voids (Ie 1,2,3,4) exists and not 1,3,4,6)  IF the latter, I can correct. (will use a limit/order descending)

assumes you want the avg of the 2 grades per person/per quiz.

Explanation:
Executes a sub query to : get quiz, user where attempt is equal to max attempt for the same quiz/user less 1.  Performance isn't ideal there is likely a faster way but this shold work.

```
SELECT T1.quiz, T1.userID, avg(T1.grade)
FROM TABLE T1
   T1.Attempt >= 
    (Select max(T3.attempt) -1
     from table T3
     where T3.QUIZ=T1.Quiz 
     AND T3.UserID=T1.UserID)
GROUP BY T1.Quiz, T1.UserID
```

Comment: Hi xObert, I don't have one more table, as everything is in one table

Comment: Table is the same in both cases: its a subselect to get max-1 attempt per user per quiz.  (use the same name in both spots).  So if your table name is SCORES: then replace Table with SCORES in both places.

Comment: This is the error i am getting when I execute the query " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T1.attempt &gt;= (SELECT MAX(T3.attempt) -1 FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track T3' at line 3