# MySQL last two rows

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Query for Average of last 2 attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524936/mysql-query-for-average-of-last-2-attempts)

```
userid scormid attempt Grade
3        12      1      83% 
3        12      2      20%
3        12      3      36%
3        12      4      80%
3        12      5      40%
```

I need the average grade (ie., (80+40)/2) only for the last two attempts
This is the second time I am rising a question, as no one gave me a correct solution for my previous question. Please guys kindly help me with this query

Comment: Please do not ask the same question again. If you're not satisfied with answers to your earlier one, consider editing the question to clarify your need. The editing activity will push it back into the active questions.

Comment: add the stuff from the commentspree in your question, and add what is wrong. in the other question obviously

Comment: Please do not re-post the same question, especially since you've got a high-quality answer last time.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have edited the question twice and twice, even though it  didn't worked out And you guys saying that I got a high-quality answer, You could tell me which one?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(grade)/2
FROM your_table
ORDER by id ASC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: No this isn't the exact answer I feel